# Resolve debug symbols for postgres

Tags: postgresql, debug-symbols, citus

I am working on an adding a new extension on citus and am in the process of collecting and analyzing the stack traces for the extension, postgres, citus and other libs by running ycsb workloads against a cluster. I am using perfcollect to collect and perfview to view the stack traces. In the traces for the postmaster processes I am finding a lot of "unknown" modules which I believe are unresolved postgres symbols-

[unknown_symbols_png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvAHh.png)

I have tried several things to resolve these symbols -

1. Build postgres from source with debug flags for the configure file (--enable-debug, CFLAGS = -ggdb -O0 -g)
2. Build postgres using yum package manager - this builds the debug symbols and executables in different folders, so have to then use eu-unstrip command to combine the symbols and executables into a single file
3. Build the extension with debug symbols

None of this has helped me resolve the unknown symbols when using perfcollect. However, when trying to collect the traces using the linux perf tool with the specific PID for postgres and then using the Firefox profiler tool to view the traces, I see much less unknown modules - some are still there though.

Any ideas what else can be done to resolve these unknown symbols?